# How to add SYLT(synced lyrics) tag on ID3v2 mp3 file using python?

Tags: python, mp3, id3v2

I want to add synced lyrics from vtt on my mp3 file using python. I tried using the mutagen module but it didn't work as intended.

```py
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, USLT, SLT
import sys
import webvtt

lyrics = webvtt.read(sys.argv[2])
lyri = []
lyr = []
for lyric in lyrics:
    times = [int(x) for x in lyric.start.replace(".", ":").split(":")]
    ms = times[-1]+1000*times[-2]+1000*60*times[-3]+1000*60*60*times[-4]
    lyri.append((lyric.text,ms))
    lyr.append(lyric.text)
fil = ID3(sys.argv[1])
tag = USLT(encoding=3, lang='kor', text="\n".join(lyr)) # this is unsynced lyrics
#tag = SLT(encoding=3, lang='kor', format=2, type=1, text=lyri) --- not working
print(tag)
fil.add(tag)
fil.save(v1=0)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you reached a solution since? I would be happy if you share.

Comment: Interested in that application too. Please keep me posted if this is offered as a user application (CLI or GUI).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use mutagen to parse an mp3 file that already has SYLT data, and found the usage of SYLT:

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, SYLT, Encoding

tag = ID3(mp3path)
sync_lrc = [("Do you know what's worth fighting for", 17640), 
            ("When it's not worth dying for?", 23640), ...]  # [(lrc, millisecond), ]
tag.setall("SYLT", [SYLT(encoding=Encoding.UTF8, lang='eng', format=2, type=1, text=sync_lrc)])
tag.save(v2_version=3)
```

But I can't figure out `format=2, type=1` means.

Answer (score 2):

check
https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Synchronised_lyrics.2Ftext

- format 1: Absolute time, 32 bit sized, using MPEG frames as unit
- format 2: Absolute time, 32 bit sized, using milliseconds as unit
- type 0:     is other
- type 1:     is lyrics
- type 2 :    is text transcription
- type 3  :   is movement/part name (e.g. "Adagio")
- type 4  :   is events (e.g. "Don Quijote enters the stage")
- type 5  :   is chord (e.g. "Bb F Fsus")
- type 6  :   is trivia/'pop up' information